# File Upload Failing Mysteriously in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, directory, tmp

I'm trying to upload a file to my server using the CakePHP file upload form helper.
I am currently running CakePHP 1.3 on my development computer (Mac OSX).
When the form submits, it has in the variables that are passed to the controller its temp name: `/var/tmp/name` and then its name as the name of the file.
However, when I try to rename the file to a more permanent location, it fails, and if I go to the location, it doesn't exist.

I get these error messages:

```
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(Users/chustar/Documents/IMAG0001.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 41]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/php98lzsP' to '/Users/chustar/Documents/IMAG0001.jpg' [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 41]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Library/WebServer/Documents/cake/libs/debugger.php:673) [CORE/cake/
```

Comment: How do you know it fails? What is the error message?

Comment: I would try to resolve that 3rd error: "Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Library/WebServer/Documents/cake/libs/debugger.php:673) [CORE/cake/"  That may just involve disabling something, for the time being.  Basically, you want to simplify things, in order to isolate the cause of the issue.

Comment: The 3rd error is usually a result of the first two. The error messages get displayed which creates the output that prevents headers from being modified.

Comment: @Rob Wilkerson Fair enough, I assumed that to be errors in a log file, not a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this error a lot when I don't have permissions set properly on the target directory. For the purposes of illustration, I'm going to assume that you're running an Apache web server and that it's running as a user named `www`. That `www` user must have write access to the target directory. It's not about what permissions **you** have, but what permissions the web server user has.

If you find that not to be the problem, a few more specifics and/or some code may be helpful.

Comment: Was writing to the My Documents folder for sonme reason. So apache didn't have write permissions there. Solved.